# Connecting input field and button boostrap modal

Tags: css, user-interface, web, bootstrap-modal, frontend

I am trying to connect my input field and button while keeping the field  centered on my modal. IE not floated left or right

[Currently it looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFpnq.png)

[I want it to look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Kzx.png)

HTML---

```
                <div class="input-append">
                    <input id="input-zip" type="search" placeholder="Enter zip code"/>
                    <span class="input-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-zip" data-dismiss="modal">CONTINUE</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

CSS----

```
.btn-zip {
    float: right;
    background: map-get($colors, bg-btn-card);
    color: map-get($colors, button-text);
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

JQUERY--

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $('#zip-modal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex comes to the rescue:

```
.input-append{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

`width: 100%` - expands element to fit the entire line horizontally, from that width, the center is calculated

`justify-content` - inner items are centered horizontally

`align-items` - inner items are centered vertically

Comment: thank you so much! worked like a charm :) Now i just need to button and input field aligned